# Calculate the median of the 20 peers that are closest in terms of total assets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to calculate the median P/E ratio of the 20 firms that are closest to the firm to be valued in terms of total assets.

I got all my company (S&P 500) tickers in column C, the respective total assets in column I, and the P/E ratios in column Z.

I got this formula but there's the condition missing that I just want to have the closest 20 companies to be considered for the median.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($I$4:$I$508= |||the 20 closest companies or +/-10% of the value|||| )*($B$4:$B$508<>$B4);$Z$4:$Z$508))
```

If that's not possible in Excel, I'm going for a range of values, where the totals assets can be like +/- 10% compared to the firm to be valued.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  Thanks for the test file.  The results are shown in the table below. The screenshot shows the first 25 rows, but the actual table includes all the data in your test file.

[image]

The helper column ("∆ Assets", Column E) is the absolute value of the difference between the assets of the company to be valued, and all the other companies.  Cell H6 holds the test company assets, and can easily be changed to point to any company in the list. In this example, it points to B4. The formula in E4 is:

`=ABS($E4-$H$6)`

And it is filled down to create the helper column.  The formula in H4 is:

`=MEDIAN(IF(RANK(E4:E55,E4:E55,1)<22,D4:D55))`

This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As a check, I calculated the median P/E manually in G4 by selecting the 21 P/E's according to the rank of the helper column in Column F.  The results are the same as using the formula, so both methods ignore the cells where the P/E is "NA".  BUT, if these cells are made blank, the calculated median changes because the inner array contains zero where the NA's were.

How it works:  The RANK() function returns an array of the ranks of the values of the helper column in ascending order.  The IF() returns an array of the 21 P/E ratios corresponding to the companies with assets nearest to the company being valued.  (Note: I used 21 because I assume the company being valued is in the list.  If not, change the formula accordingly.) Finally, MEDIAN() calculates the median value of the array of 21 asset values.

I was a bit surprised to find that RANK() could handle two arrays as arguments, but not *calculated* arrays, i.e ABS($I$4:$I$508-$I$nn).  This is why the helper column was necessary.  Even more bizarre - RANK() can handle **ONE** calculated array, but not two.  This deserves a "C'mon man..." for sure.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work. I get the #VALUE! error 
Would your solution mean I needed a helper column for every company I want to value? That would be quite uncomfortable, wouldnt it?

Comment: No, just one helper column. I tested this and it works correctly on sample data that I simulated. Can you post (or share in another way) a real sample of your data? 25 rows or so, including at least Columns I and Z.  And the location of the test company's assets.  A screenshot would be fine.  Edit your question and add one if you can.  If you can't, add a link to the pic, and I'll insert it.

Comment: Hey, I uploaded a test file with ~50 companies here: https://we.tl/D227kzB7Bs Looking forward to your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

While Rank doesn't accept calculated arrays (a surprise to me as well), Small does:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(IF($C$4:$C$508=C4,"",ABS(I4-$I$4:$I$508))<=SMALL(IF($C$4:$C$508=C4,"",ABS(I4-$I$4:$I$508)),20),$Z$4:$Z$508)) {Array Entered}
```

The inner IF statement excludes the target company. Otherwise it operates almost identically to Bandersnatch's solution.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution in Excel? I still get a #VALUE!

Comment: Do you happen to have any #VALUE! errors in any of the cells the formula is referencing? Or text values in your Asset column? Either of those will cause the formula to fail.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Got some "NA"s where there is no total asset value for a specific company. If I delete them, it's working! Thank you so much!

Comment: do you have any idea for my other question? Combining two criteria progressively?:/

Answer (score 0):

Got one more question. Now I want to combine TA and ROE. The objective is to find the 5 companies closest to the target company in terms of TA and then the 3 companies from those 5 which are closest in terms of ROE!

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Test file available here: https://we.tl/rNIrgWL9h8

Thank you so much for helping out guys!

@Nayrb